# How can I configure the value of `-container-network` in selenoid for every jenkins build?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, yaml, selenoid

Every Jenkins build creates a network before running the selenoid tests. e.g.,

`Creating network "jenkinspr613build11_default"`. 
The network name is based on the PR and build number.

The docker-compose.yaml file, had the below config for selenoid service:

```
selenoid:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid:latest-release"
    command: -listen :4444 -conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json -limit 6 -video-output-dir /opt/selenoid/video/ -timeout 3m -container-network jenkinswebpr613build11_default
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

How can I configure the value of `-container-network` for every build?

Can I pass an environment variable to the yaml file?

I can start the tests locally when I hard-code the value of `-container-network`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the network name changed with every Jenkins build, I used a different solution:

The value of Network was set to a command line variable `${NETWORK_TAG}` as shown below:

```
selenoid:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid:latest-release"
    command: -listen :4444 -conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json -limit 6 -video-output-dir /opt/selenoid/video/ -timeout 3m -container-network ${NETWORK_TAG}
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

The docker-compose up command was run as follows:

```
NETWORK_TAG=$JENKINS_NETWORK_NAME docker-compose -f docker-compose-selenoid.yml up --build
```

The value of `$JENKINS_NETWORK_NAME` was dynamically set for every Jenkins build.

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose` builds network name from project name (can be passed explicitly with `-p` parameter to `docker-compose up`) and internal name.

To specify internal network, just write it explicitly in `docker-compose.yml` file and link all services to it like:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenoid:
    ...
  networks:
    - my-lovely-net

networks:
  my-lovely-net:
```

Also, if you don't want to recreate network each time but instead want to reuse global one, you have to first create it like `docker network create foo` and then tell `docker-compose` that the network is external:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenoid:
    ...
  networks:
    - my-lovely-net

networks:
  my-lovely-net:
    external: true
    name: foo
```

Comment: A small addition. Selenoid is just a web-service. So nothing special. A generic Docker Compose answer will work.